# Em R, usar fread em uma conexao shh com pipe

Tags: r, ssh

Eu tenho uma máquina virtual com muitos arquivos TXT. Eu costumo usar uma conexão ssh e pipe para poder ler os arquivos. Quando eu uso a funcao read.csv não há problema nenhum na hora de ler os arquivos. Já quando eu uso a função fread, o negócio não dá certo. Mostro primeiro o caso que dá certo!

```
 # my directory with the plink intallation (plink.exe)
 dir<- "C/Tools/Terminal/"
 setwd(dir)

 user <- 'XXXXXX'
 password <- 'XXXX'
 dir_file_machine <- '/media/projects/'
 name_file <- 'XXXXXX.TXT'
 capture_file <- pipe(paste0('plink -ssh ', 
                              user, 
                              '@123.45.678.901 -P 12 -pw ', #fictice 
                              password, 
                              ' "cat ', 
                              dir_file_machine, 
                              name_file))

 a <- read.csv(capture_file, sep = ";")
```

Agora, quando eu uso a função fread acontece o seguinte erro...

```
 capture_file <- pipe(paste0('plink -ssh ', 
                              user, 
                              '@123.45.678.901 -P 12 -pw ', #fictional 
                              password, 
                              ' "cat ', 
                              dir_file_machine, 
                              name_file))

 a <- fread(capture_file, sep = ";")
 Error in fread(capture_file) : 
'input' must be a single character string containing a file name, a command, full path to a file, a URL starting 'http[s]://', 'ftp[s]://' or 'file://', or the input data itself
```

Alguma ideia?

Comment: A função `read.csv` aceita conexões como um dos inputs. Já a `fread`, não... Acredito que não exista um jeito fácil para corrigir isso.

Comment: De acordo com o comentário [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32902057/can-data-tables-fread-accept-connections#comment53632675_32902057) e a documentação, você pode passar o  comando direto para o `fread`, sem o `pipe`. Não tenho como testar aqui, mas em princípio deveria funcionar removendo o `pipe` apenas.

Comment: @Molx interessante!! Retiro o meu comentário :P

Comment: Sim, funciona. Obrigado

Comment: @Molx seria legal você colocar seu comentário como resposta, não acha?

Comment: @DanielFalbel De fato, não notei que ele confirmou o funcionamento. Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na realidade para fazer isto basta remover o `pipe`, pois o próprio `fread` já faz o *piping* do comando:

```
capture_file <- paste0('plink -ssh ', 
                       user, 
                       '@123.45.678.901 -P 12 -pw ', #fictional 
                       password, 
                       ' "cat ', 
                       dir_file_machine, 
                       name_file)
a <- fread(capture_file, sep = ";")
```

Note que isto está na [documentação](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/data.table.pdf) do `fread`:

> input
>
> Either the file name to read (containing no \n character), **a shell command that preprocesses the file (e.g. fread("grep blah filename")** or the input itself as a string (containing at least one \n), see examples. I

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32902057/can-data-tables-fread-accept-connections#comment53632675_32902057).